# Recycle-safe thread ID's and when thread stack gets freed?

Tags: windows, multithreading, memory-management

Does the stack reserved/commited for a thread get freed when

- the thread terminates
- the thread object is destroyed
  (i.e. the thread is terminated and all handles to the thread are closed)

?

More broadly, are there significant resources associated with a thread that has terminated, but still exists since there are valid handles to it?

---

Reason: I need to modify a kind of "scoped singleton", so it doesn't return a single object, but a per-thread object. I cannot rely on thread creation/termination notices, much less on process-wide ones.

At the moment, I store the objects in a `map<ThreadID, Object>`, with a cache cleanup policy that's suitable for my application.  To protect myself from the OS "recycling" thread ID's, I keep an handle to the thread open. (Rec

A side effect would be holding open handles to long-terminated threads in some corner cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to ["Windows VIA C/C++"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735624240) by Richter and Nasarre (A must-have book for any C++ Windwos programmer) p.154:

> **Terminating a Thread**
>
> A thread can be terminated in four
>   ways:
>
> - The thread function returns. (This is highly recommended.)
> - The thread kills itself by calling the ExitThread function. (Avoid this
>     method.)
> - A thread in the same process or in another one calls the TerminateThread
>     function. (Avoid this method.)
> - The process containing the thread terminates. (Avoid this method.)
>
> **The Thread Function Returns**
>
> You should always design your thread
>   functions so that they return when you
>   want the thread to terminate. This is
>   the only way to guarantee that all
>   your thread's resources are cleaned up
>   properly.
>
> Having your thread function return
>   ensures the following:
>
> - All C++ objects created in your thread function will be destroyed
>     properly via their destructors.
> - The operating system will properly free the memory used by the thread's
>     stack.
> - The system will set the thread's exit code (maintained in the thread's
>     kernel object) to your thread
>     function's return value.
> - The system will decrement the usage count of the thread's kernel object.
>
> **The ExitThread Function**
>
> You can force your thread to terminate by having it call ExitThread:
>
> VOID ExitThread(DWORD dwExitCode);
>
> This function terminates the thread
>   and causes the operating system to
>   clean up all the operating system
>   resources that were used by the
>   thread. However, your C/C++ resources
>   (such as C++ class objects) will not
>   be destroyed. For this reason, it is
>   much better to simply return from your
>   thread function instead of calling
>   ExitThread yourself.
>
> Of course, you use ExitThread's
>   dwExitCode parameter to tell the
>   system what to set the thread's exit
>   code to. The ExitThread function does
>   not return a value because the thread
>   has terminated and cannot execute any
>   more code.
>
> Note  The recommended way to have a
>   thread terminate is by having its
>   thread function simply return (as
>   described in the previous section).
>   However, if you use the method
>   described in this section, be aware
>   that the ExitThread function is the
>   Windows function that kills a thread.
>   If you are writing C/C++ code, you
>   should never call ExitThread. Instead,
>   you should use the C++ run-time
>   library function _endthreadex. If you
>   do not use Microsoft's C++ compiler,
>   your compiler vendor will have its own
>   alternative to ExitThread. Whatever
>   this alternative is, you must use it.
>
> **The TerminateThread Function**
>
> A call to
>   TerminateThread also kills a thread:
>
> BOOL TerminateThread(    HANDLE
>   hThread,    DWORD dwExitCode);
>
> Unlike ExitThread, which always kills
>   the calling thread, TerminateThread
>   can kill any thread. The hThread
>   parameter identifies the handle of the
>   thread to be terminated. When the
>   thread terminates, its exit code
>   becomes the value you passed as the
>   dwExitCode parameter. Also, the
>   thread's kernel object has its usage
>   count decremented.
>
> Note  The TerminateThread function is
>   asynchronous. That is, it tells the
>   system that you want the thread to
>   terminate but the thread is not
>   guaranteed to be killed by the time
>   the function returns. If you need to
>   know for sure that the thread has
>   terminated, you might want to call
>   WaitForSingleObject or a similar function,
>   passing the handle of the thread.
>
> A well-designed application never uses
>   this function because the thread being
>   terminated receives no notification
>   that it is dying. The thread cannot
>   clean up properly, and it cannot
>   prevent itself from being killed.
>
> Note  When a thread dies by returning
>   or calling ExitThread, the stack for
>   the thread is destroyed. However, if
>   TerminateThread is used, the system
>   does not destroy the thread's stack
>   until the process that owned the
>   thread terminates. Microsoft purposely
>   implemented TerminateThread in this
>   way. If other still-executing threads
>   were to reference values on the
>   forcibly killed thread's stack, these
>   other threads would raise access
>   violations. By leaving the killed
>   thread's stack in memory, other
>   threads can continue to execute just
>   fine.
>
> In addition, dynamic-link libraries
>   (DLLs) usually receive notifications
>   when a thread is terminating. If a
>   thread is forcibly killed with
>   TerminateThread, however, the DLLs do
>   not receive this notification, which
>   can prevent proper cleanup.
>
> **When a Thread Terminates**
>
> The following actions occur when a
>   thread terminates:
>
> All User object handles owned by the
>   thread are freed. In Windows, most
>   objects are owned by the process
>   containing the thread that creates the
>   objects. However, a thread owns two
>   User objects: windows and hooks. When
>   a thread dies, the system
>   automatically destroys any windows and
>   uninstalls any hooks that were created
>   or installed by the thread. Other
>   objects are destroyed only when the
>   owning process terminates.
>
> The thread's exit code changes from
>   STILL_ACTIVE to the code passed to
>   ExitThread or TerminateThread.
>
> The state of the thread kernel object
>   becomes signaled.
>
> If the thread is the last active
>   thread in the process, the system
>   considers the process terminated as
>   well.
>
> The thread kernel object's usage count
>   is decremented by 1.
>
> When a thread terminates, its
>   associated thread kernel object
>   doesn't automatically become freed
>   until all the outstanding references
>   to the object are closed.
>
> Once a thread is no longer running,
>   there isn't much any other thread in
>   the system can do with the thread's
>   handle. However, these other threads
>   can call GetExitCodeThread to check
>   whether the thread identified by
>   hThread has terminated and, if it has,
>   determine its exit code:
>
> BOOL GetExitCodeThread(    HANDLE
>   hThread,    PDWORD pdwExitCode);
>
> The exit code value is returned in the
>   DWORD pointed to by pdwExitCode. If
>   the thread hasn't terminated when
>   GetExitCodeThread is called, the
>   function fills the DWORD with the
>   STILL_ACTIVE identifier (defined as
>   0x103). If the function is successful,
>   TRUE is returned.

Comment: a bit much, but contains what i was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `pthread_getspecific`, `pthread_setspecific` and `pthread_key_create` to manage your per thread singleton.

Comment: I wish I could - I have to deal with callers using different / unknown thread libraries, not sure if getting pthreads involved makes things simpler. Thanks for pointing out, though.